# How to apply a function to every value in a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I had tried doing a somewhat manual approach using a loop like below:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/training.csv')
for idx,imageString in enumerate(data.iloc[:,-1]):
    # print(imageString[0:10])
    data[idx,-1] = imageString.split(" ")
```

But this errors out on the last line with:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

So my questions are:

1. Can anyone explain why I am getting the above error and how can I
   get around it?
2. Is this the proper way to apply a `split` to every
   value in the last column of my data frame?

Regarding #2 - I saw some people using `applymap` but I think this creates a new column, I really just want to replace the value in the existing column with another list.

Comment: data[data.columns[-1]] = data.iloc[:,-1].map(lambda x: x.split(' '))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/training.csv')
data.iloc[:,-1] = data.iloc[:,-1].str.split(expand=False)
```

Then select first or some another elements of lists with `str[1]` or `str[n]`:

```
data.iloc[:,-1] = data.iloc[:,-1].str.split(expand=False).str[0]
data.iloc[:,-1] = data.iloc[:,-1].str.split(expand=False).str[n]
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':['aa aa','ss uu','ee tt']})

print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E      F
0  1  4  7  1  5  aa aa
1  2  5  8  3  3  ss uu
2  3  6  9  5  6  ee tt

print (data.iloc[:,-1].str.split(expand=False))
0    [aa, aa]
1    [ss, uu]
2    [ee, tt]
Name: F, dtype: object

data.iloc[:,-1] = data.iloc[:,-1].str.split(expand=False).str[0]
print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E   F
0  1  4  7  1  5  aa
1  2  5  8  3  3  ss
2  3  6  9  5  6  ee
```

---

```
data.iloc[:,-1] = data.iloc[:,-1].str.split(expand=False).str[1]
print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E   F
0  1  4  7  1  5  aa
1  2  5  8  3  3  uu
2  3  6  9  5  6  tt
```

> Can anyone explain why I am getting the above error and how can I get around it?

Problem is `imageString.split(" ")` return `list` and if assign to `data[idx,-1]`, length of elements of strings is less as length of all DataFrame.

> Is this the proper way to apply a split to every value in the last column of my data frame?

Better is use string methods, see [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings).

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the values correctly.

To correct your code, the last line should be:

```
df.iat[idx, -1] = imageString.split(" ")
```

`iat` is used for scalar getting and setting.

This is probably a simpler way to accomplish your objective:

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].str.split()
```